# Characters following a slash and ending before a hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I've been playing around with regex for a bit and regex visualizations, but have had no luck in generating something that will match a section of a url that is text of variable length preceeded by a forward slash and terminated by a hyphen. What expression would do this?

```
www.lamp.com/;alskfjdlkfja;sdlkfjasldfj-209
```

but not

```
www.lamp.com/a;slkfja;sdlkfjas;dflkj
```

because that doesn't contain a hyphen

Comment: can you give an example of the text input and what you'd like to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
/[^-]+-
```

where:

- `/` is a literal `/`
- `[^-]+` is one or more non-hyphens
- `-` is a literal `-`

---

Using your examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> url1 = 'www.lamp.com/;alskfjdlkfja;sdlkfjasldfj-209'
>>> url2 = 'www.lamp.com/a;slkfja;sdlkfjas;dflkj'
>>> 
>>> re.search(r'/[^-]+-', url1) is not None
True
>>> re.search(r'/[^-]+-', url2) is not None
False
```

Comment: Be careful that the forward-slash doesn't interfere with the regex delimiters.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Good point, but in Python that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might you first want to start with urlparse, http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html,
to get to the section of a url, but only if it really matched.